# Class with multiple images, want text on the images

Tags: css, html, image, text

I want to make this:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7KFm.png)
I have the pictures aligned, but I can't figure out how to put text on in. This is what I have now, the text positions next to the images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C18mB.png)
I think the problem is that the 6 images are inside a class. And I think I have to put each image in a seperate div. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="afbeeldingen">
   <div>
      <img src="images/boomkikker.jpg" alt="boomkikker" class="foto boomkikker" />
      <span class="tekst">Boomkikker</span>
   </div>
   <img src="images/papegaai.jpg" alt="papegaai" class="foto papegaai" />
   <div class="clearfix-klein"></div>
   <img src="images/huiskat.jpg" alt="huiskat" class="foto huiskat" />
   <div class="clearfix-groot"></div>
   <img src="images/forel.jpg" alt="forel" class="foto forel" />
   <div class="clearfix-klein"></div>
   <img src="images/shitzu.jpg" alt="Shi Tzu" class="foto shitzu" />
   <img src="images/aalscholver.jpg" alt="aalscholver" class="foto aalscholver"/>
   <div class="clearfix-groot"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.afbeeldingen {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;    
}

.clearfix-klein:after, .clearfix-groot:after {
    display: none;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a demo in Jsfiddle ?.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" />    
      <h2>A Movie in the Park:<br />Kung Fu Panda</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 5%; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tx9fddx9/

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrap all of the pictures with ex: `.div { width: 900px; height: auto;)` Also, I don't think you need an indivisual div wrapped around each image. Then you can place the float: left; property on every image Ex: img `{ float: left; }` . Your problem is that the text that you are trying to place should be `h1 position: absolute;` in order for it to be inside the image.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a wrapper for each image being on `position:relative` and the text inside it on `position:absolute` to it stays on top of the image.

Have a look at this example for one image : https://jsfiddle.net/o244xcpz/1/